# Federal, state, and county prisons & jails

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, government, geocoding

Looking for a list of all city, state, and federal related prisons & jails in the united states.

Looking for the list to include the name of facility, type, and address.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

You can start with the [US Bureau of Justice Statistics: Corrections](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=tp&tid=1) page.

In particular: [State and federal prisoners and prison facilities](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=tp&tid=13)

And perhaps of interest: [Annual Survey of Jails Data Series](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/series/7) - ([2014 edition](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/studies/36274))

Also related: [Criminal Hall of Justice](https://hallofjustice.sunlightfoundation.com/)